# Recovering root password in MySQL (XAMPP)

Tags: mysql

I have an XAMPP MySQL installation and want to recover the root password. I am aware that questions have asked this already, however they are Linux methods of doing it (I'm on Windows) and I can't seem to figure out what exactly the Linux commands translate to in XAMPP - I tried looking for a place to configure the arguments to not use network etc but couldn't.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Comment: @Marc There are other questions requesting the same thing on this site. (but the answers are for Ubuntu and don't apply to me)

Comment: Have you tried with this - in case you have server root access: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

Recovering the exact current password is apparently not possible. This solution is for resetting a lost password on a Windows machine.

I have tested this code for 5.7[.22] (while upgrading to 8.0). Please verify your installed version and paths accordingly. (x86 machines will have slightly modified values)

-

1. Stop `MySQL server` from the services, if it is running.
2. Create a file `mysql-init.txt` in D:\ drive and put the following line in it:

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewRootPassWillComeHere';`

3. Open command prompt and execute the following commands:

`C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"`

`C:\> mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\my.ini" --init-file=D:\\mysql-init.txt --console`

The option `--console` will give the output in the command prompt.

4. Password has been reset successfully and the file `mysql-init.txt` can be deleted.

-

Source and other scenarios: [How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)